# User tracking and data sending in a background service in Android

Tags: android, service, thread-safety, threadpool

**Details**

The app has a background service running when the app is started. In this service, on `onStartCommand()` starts listening for GPS location with a parameter for passed meters between reads. Let's say 50 meters for example. Each time a location is read the following operations occur:

- read location is stored in a local database
- retrieve all unsent location from the database
- location(s) is sent to a web server
- if sending is successful, the location(s) is deleted from the database

Now this behavior happens every time a location is read.The user might be walking which takes some time to make the 50 meters or drive fast, while many reads can be done and things might get messy in the database insert/retrieve. So one of the main requests is to have all read locations processed sequentially, as they were read. Something like: read location 1, insert it, send it... read location 2, insert it, send it.

I can't find out a proper way to do this. As you know, the service runs in the same main thread as the app, so I definitely need to use threading to keep the UI running smooth.

I was thinking to use ExecutorService and a Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() to which to submit new threads each time a location is read. In this way, I make sure processing is done in sequence but... I make new threads for each read, which might not be such a good thing.

What best approach would you suggest for this situation ?

Comment: Yea,  use the ExecutorService & Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() .... or wrap everything in asynctasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is remove the service and throw an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) every time a location is read.

You can use [requestLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) with pending intent argument, and set the pending intent argument with an intent that triggers your intent service.

In the intentservice's *onHandleIntent* you can then handle the location update. Intents are handled sequentially by intent service, and it handles them in a separate thread (and then expires).

If you just need to consume one shot events on background, intentservice are a more compact and suitable solution.

Comment: I do need to use the background service to constantly track the location. But, your idea sounds interesting. So let me see if I get things streight: In my service, each time a location is read, all I need to do is start the intent service and pass the read location to it. This intent service, in `onHandleIntent` will add the current job to a work queue. So, each time a location is read, the location processing is added in this work queue. Won't the intent service shut down after first location is processed ?

Comment: It's a lot simpler. If you set the pending intent with an intent that triggers your intentservice, your intentservice will be triggered for free. Every intent of this type is put in a queue and handled by the intent service in a separate thread. The intent service dies when the onHandleIntent returns. What you need to worry about is only the business logic.

Comment: You need to use public void requestLocationUpdates (long minTime, float minDistance, Criteria criteria, PendingIntent intent) (the one with pendingintent argumetn)

Comment: Sorry I can't edit the previous comments. What do you mean by monitoring the location changes? If you set the listener properly, an intent will be triggered every time the location changes. I think you want to handle the changes sequentially, so you can do that using the intentservice

Comment: I've updated my code to use IntentService and it seems to be running great. It's interesting to see that all Intents are handles one after another, I though they will be async. Great answer, thanks for your help. I will continue to test and get back with the final result.